# JQGrid cannot isolate changes across the jQuery ui-tabs. When a row is edited, grids on other tabs also get updated

Tags: jqgrid

My page layout is exactly as you see in Jqgrid demo page http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

When a user selects from the menu grid on the left pane, a tab is dynamically created on the right pane with a Subgrid. The grids are all identical accross the tabs. The id value is overriden with key set to true in colModel. But the problem is when an update is made on any tab, other tabs also get updated even though the grid name and id not the same. The only thing they have in common is that they all have similar columns definitions
How can I isolate the changes made on one tab so that they do not get into grids in other tabs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The grid id was assigned to a global variable rather than local.

Before ....

```
$grid = $("#MainGrid" + recordId);<br/>
                $grid.jqGrid({<br/>
                    regional: 'en',<br/>
                    datatype: "json",<br/>
                    url: encodeURI('@.........<br/>
```

After ......

```
$("#MainGrid" + recordId).jqGrid({<br/>
                    regional: 'en',<br/>
                    datatype: "json",<br/>
                    url: encodeURI('@Ur........<br/>
```

Changed to local (as in **After** above) and problem now resolved